Add lighters to minor modes that seem to lack them
A couple of the minor modes I use I tend to want to toggle on and off relatively often. To be able to quickly see the state of which of these minor modes I have toggled I do the following:

Use (diminish '<minor-mode>) on all minor-modes I will always have enabled and never toggle.
Use (diminish '<minor-mode> "<SOME-DESCRIPTIVE-CHARACTER>) on all the minor-modes I toggle relatively often.

Now this works fine in principle. But I have trouble setting a lighter for electric-pair-mode and electric-layout-mode while I can set the lighter for electric-spacing-mode just fine.
Is the issue that the electric-{pair,layout}-modes don't have a lighter set at all and diminish doesn't handle that?
Here's a minimal config showing the issue:
(use-package emacs
  :bind (
         :prefix-map ctl-z-map
         :prefix-docstring "My keys"
         :prefix "C-z"
         ( "u"           . insert-char)

         :prefix-map ctl-z-toggle-map
         :prefix-docstring "Toggle"
         :prefix "C-z t"
         ( "f"           . auto-fill-mode)

         :prefix-map ctl-z-toggle-electric-map
         :prefix-docstring "Toggle (Electric)"
         :prefix "C-z t e"))

(use-package diminish
  :ensure t)

;; Eldoc
(use-package eldoc
  :defer t
  :diminish)

;; Electric
(use-package electric
  :diminish (electric-layout-mode . " ⏎")
  :hook (prog-mode . electric-layout-mode)
  :bind ( :map ctl-z-toggle-electric-map
          ("l"     . electric-layout-mode)))

(use-package elec-pair
  :diminish (electric-pair-mode . " ❮❯")
  :hook (prog-mode . electric-pair-mode)
  :bind ( :map ctl-z-toggle-electric-map
          ("p"     . electric-pair-mode)))

(use-package electric-spacing
  :ensure t
  :diminish (electric-spacing-mode . " ⊕")
  :hook (prog-mode . electric-spacing-mode)
  :bind ( :map ctl-z-toggle-electric-map
          ("s"     . electric-spacing-mode)))



Is the issue that the electric-{pair,layout}-modes don't have a lighter set at all and diminish doesn't handle that?

Indeed.
Minor mode lighters are stored in minor-mode-alist.  The define-minor-mode macro produces a call to add-minor-mode with the NAME argument set to the specified lighter, and if NAME is nil then nothing is added.
The likes of diminish were written to modify or eliminate existing lighters, rather than add lighters to modes which never had them to start with, so they'll be looking to modify an existing entry in the list, rather than adding a new entry.  It's an easy fix if the use-case occurs but, speaking as the author of a similar library, it never occurred to me either.
You can easily work around this:
(add-to-list 'minor-mode-alist '(electric-pair-mode " pair"))
(add-to-list 'minor-mode-alist '(electric-layout-mode " layout"))


Thanks a bunch!
